# Parent div not aligning to center when window scaled

Tags: html, css

Whenever I rescale/resize my window to smaller size (smartphone sized) all of the three inner div's (.left .center .right) red,green,blue respectively,  below each other doesn't align to the center. Please see the attached screenshot to understand. I want all of these three div's to be in the center of the main .container div (pink) whenever the window is scaled down. Would appreciate your inputs.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  max-width: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(216, 86, 112, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: block;
  right: 0px;
}
.top {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 51, 0, 1);
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 331px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  top: 0px;
}
.center {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 331px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 331px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>

  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You float them to left, and set their widths explicitly. They wouldn't go center. Or you can use [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to decide how they should behave on mobile platform.

Answer (score 0):

My method is to have separate code for css that overwrites the code when the conditions are met. For this you would decide what you want to max width to be before it changes and add the code:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1187px)
        {
            new css here
        }
```

For your particular project you would just have to change the floats and margins (and the width that you want (the 1187 here)) so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1187px)
            {
            .left {
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
float:none;
}
.center {
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
float:none;
}
.right {
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
float:none;
}

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

UPD. **Three blocks int the center of the parent**

I have seen the cooment about three blocks< which are centered like `- - -`. This is my solution.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  background-color: rgba(216, 86, 112, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
.top {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(204, 51, 0, 1);
  height: 10%;
}
.left,
.center,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 331px;
}
.left   { background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1); }
.center { background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1); }
.right  { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>

  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Media query**

I prefer the mobile first design. The first step is to adjust the webpage for a smartphone. Then determine the changes that occur when the screen becomes wider. Then describe the changes for an even wider screen. And so on.

Let's calculate the width of the screen, in which the three blocks will fit in the same row. Three 331px wide blocks occupied by 993px. This is 90% of the screen width. 10% falls on the margins of the container. Therefore

```
993px x 100% / 90% = 1104px
```

So I've added a media query for this breakpoint.

Also I've commented out the parts that are not needed to solve described problem. Please check the result.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  /*
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  */
}
.container {
  background-color: rgba(216, 86, 112, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  /*
  margin-top: auto;
  display: block;
  right: 0px;
  width: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  max-width: auto;
  position: relative;
  */
}
.top {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(204, 51, 0, 1);
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  /*
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  */
}
.left,
.center,
.right {
  width: 331px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 1104px) {
  .left,
  .center,
  .right {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 331px;
    /*
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: 0px;
    */
  }
}
.left   { background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1); }
.center { background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1); }
.right  { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>

  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @serious_coder I have seen the cooment about three blocks< which are centered loke - - -. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/xofoh5yp/

Just removed floats and left position styles.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>

  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>
</div>

html,body {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  max-width: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(216, 86, 112, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: block;
  right: 0px;

}
.top {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 51, 0, 1);
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  height: auto;
  width: 331px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;

}
.center {

  width: 331px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;

}
.right {

  height: auto;
  width: 331px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;

}
```

---

Here is the code if you want them to be in one line : 
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xofoh5yp/1/

Basically, added container DIV and then added % widths.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div>
  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

html,body {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  max-width: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(216, 86, 112, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: block;
  right: 0px;

}
.top {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(204, 51, 0, 1);
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  height: auto;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  float:left;

}
.center {

  width: 33%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  float:left;

}
.right {

  height: auto;
  width: 34%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  float:left;

}
```

Another fiddle with margin : https://jsfiddle.net/xofoh5yp/2/

Comment: Ok thanks. Your above code seems to work. However it centeres the div's which are positioned one below each other. I want them to be centered together in a line ( like this --- ) with no spaces in between them.

Comment: Yes. but i want left and right equal margin of 5px (on left of .left div and on the right of .right div)

Comment: Updated Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xofoh5yp/2/ You can control the margin with mainContent div

Comment: Thanks it worked. Now in that above code which you sent, what if i want a 2px margin between .left and .center , and .center and .right divs ?

Comment: @serious_coder - It's simple: Look here https://jsfiddle.net/xofoh5yp/2/ ....And adjust the margin of this div  with class mainContent.

Comment: @serious_coder - What happened here? Did it work? If yes then mark any answer that worked for you as Answer. No point in keeping this thread open.